# Prevent spoon from accessing the JVM class path

Tags: java, inria-spoon

Is there any way, i can prevent spoon parser from accessing the JVM classpath and provide necessary jars (rt.jar etc) in launcher.setSouceClassPath() ?

Comment: Interesting question. Could you ask on Github?

Comment: https://github.com/INRIA/spoon/issues/3789 yes, here it is